# TreeListView and hierarchical checkboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I am using TreeListView with:

```
this.tlv.CheckBoxes = true;
this.tlv.TriStateCheckBoxes = true;
this.tlv.HierarchicalCheckboxes = true;
```

Hierarchical with tristate works well, except one: the user can set the CheckState.Indeterminate by clicking the mouse, and I don't need it. For this I use 2 delegate that are not working correctly. How to make that work?

```
this.tvl.CheckStateGetter = delegate(object rowObject)
{                
    if (((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked == true)
    {
        return CheckState.Checked;
    }
    else
    {
        if (((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked == false)
        {
            return CheckState.Unchecked;
        }
        else
        {
            return CheckState.Indeterminate;
        }
    }
};
this.tvl.CheckStatePutter = delegate(object rowObject, CheckState newValue)
{
    if (((ModelData)rowObject).Child.Count > 0)
    {
        if ((((ModelData)rowObject).Child.Where(x => x.IsChecked != null).Any(x => (bool)x.IsChecked) && 
            ((ModelData)rowObject).Child.Where(x => x.IsChecked != null).Any(x => !(bool)x.IsChecked)) || 
            (((ModelData)rowObject).Child.Any(x => x.IsChecked == null)))
        {                        
            ((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked = null;
            return CheckState.Indeterminate;
        }
        else
        {
            if (((ModelData)rowObject).Child.Where(x => x.IsChecked != null).All(x => (bool)x.IsChecked))
            {                            
                ((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked = true;
                return CheckState.Checked;
            }
            else
            {
                ((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked = false;
                return CheckState.Unchecked;
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ((ModelData)rowObject).IsChecked = (newValue == CheckState.Checked) ? true : false;
        return newValue;
    }                      
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, "CheckStateGetters" are not allowed in the treelistview.

From the webpage:

> One major problem is that we don’t know the checkedness of all the
>   subitems. When an ObjectListView has a CheckStateGetter installed, the
>   only way we can know if an item is checked is by calling the
>   CheckStateGetter on that item. We can’t reason about what is checked
>   or unchecked – we always have to ask. In our disk browser example, we
>   would have to ask all 700,000 items if it was checked. That’s never
>   going to work, so with hierarchical checkboxes, we don’t allow
>   CheckStateGetters to be installed.

http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/blog7.html